# How to locate a class in _tk theme to remove it?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, themes

I am having a bit of trouble trying to create a custom page template on Wordpress using the **_tk** theme (based on **_s** theme & Bootstrap). My issue is that I want to make the custom page template span the entire width of the content area after removing the side bar, but there is a class showing in the HTML inspector that is not allowing me to do this. I have included a screenshot to show what I mean.

I can remove the `col-md-8` class from the inspector and it gets me the desired result, but I can't locate it in the PHP files to remove/modify it. I am fairly new to developing/designing with Wordpress, so I'm not sure if I am even going about this the right way.

[image]

Site I am working on: `http://66.147.244.181/~slimbaby/phenomradio`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`col-md-8` is found in [header.php](https://github.com/Themekraft/_tk/blob/master/header.php) on Line #85.

You might want to simply override the CSS on that specific page though if you prefer not to edit header.php